# Docker container connecting to a MSSQL database

Tags: php, docker, dns

I have an image that I would like to use to "containerize" our PHP application connection to an MSSQL database. I start with the Dockerfile:

```
FROM nsidhaye/msphpsql

ENV ENVIRONMENT development

ENV APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT /var/www

RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/html!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/*.conf
RUN sed -ri -e 's!/var/www/!${APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT}!g' /etc/apache2/apache2.conf /etc/apache2/conf-available/*.conf

COPY MyAgsourceAPI /var/www/
COPY MyAgsourceAPI/as_sys2 /var/as_sys2
```

So I have the proper PHP drivers in place and the code has been copied. Now I would like to get some advice from users. Do I "add a network" as --network?  I must admit my understanding of a "closed container" and a "bridged container" is limited. So commands like:

```
docker run --detach --net bridge -p 80:80 rkevinburton/myagsourceapi
```

don't seem to work. How do I connect to an MSSQL server at 192.168.3.55 from a container?

Comment: Your Dockerfile does not seem to have a 

CMD

or an 

ENTRYPOINT

so it exits immediately, that is "normal", see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553353/what-is-the-difference-between-cmd-and-entrypoint-in-a-dockerfile

Comment: Microsoft has a MSSQL Docker container; so you can fire up a linked container.  Also, `docker run --add-host: name:ip` allows you to add an entry to the hosts file.  (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#managing-etchosts) I hope this helps a bit!

Comment: If you look at the image that this custom image is based on the last line in the Dockerfile is

`ENTRYPOINT ["apache2ctl", "-DFOREGROUND"]`

Comment: The application container is a Linux container. Since Windows containers are still "experimental" should the MSSQL container be a Linux container as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually accomplish this using [Docker Compose](https://docs.docker.com/compose/overview/) and its links option.

Check this tutorial https://blog.codeship.com/orchestrate-containers-for-development-with-docker-compose/